# Something strange happens with AJAX after keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, keyup

I have a problem and it's the following, I have a textbox to search contacts after execute keyup event, the contacts are appended to a div, because I use pagination with the scroll too, after keyup event the content of that div is cleaned to replace it with the new content, but this happens if I write slowly, because when I write very fast, the content is not replaced but is appended to the existing content and so that is repeating the same register, may be because ajax is asynchronous and after every keyup it remains executing the request.

**code**

```
    var paginam = 1;
    $('div.dvusuarios').scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            paginam++;
            listcontactosmsj($('#txtbuscaamgcon').val(), paginam);
        }
    });

      function listcontactosmsj(contacto, paginam) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "<? echo PUBLIC_PATH . 'message/selcontacts' ?>",
            data: 'contacto=' + contacto
                    + '&pagina=' + paginam
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('div.dvusuarios').append(data);
        });
    }

    listcontactosmsj('', 1);

    $('#txtbuscaamgcon').keyup(function() {
        paginam = 1;
        $('div.dvusuarios').html('');
        listcontactosmsj($(this).val(),paginam );
    });
```

I tried to solve it like this, but this does not work

```
 $('#txtbuscaamgcon').keyup(function() {
            paginam = 1;
            $('div.dvusuarios').html('');
            var refrescar = setInterval(listcontactosmsj($(this).val(),paginam), 5000);
             $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
        });
```

I don´t know what's wrong with my source code, the queries in mysql and php scripts are ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning, you should create a new global variable under `paginam`, like so:

```
var paginam = 1,
    contactRequest = false;
```

Then, change your `listcontactosmsj()` function to the following:

```
function listcontactosmsj(contacto, paginam) {
    if (contactRequest) {
        contactRequest.abort();
    }
    contactRequest = $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "<? echo PUBLIC_PATH . 'message/selcontacts' ?>",
        data: 'contacto=' + contacto
                + '&pagina=' + paginam
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('div.dvusuarios').append(data);
        contactRequest = false;
    });
}
```

You're right about what's happening. When you type quickly, the `keyup` event fires rapidly, and multiple AJAX requests are being sent rapidly. With this modification, the `listcontactosmsj()` function will check to see if there's currently a request being made. If there is, it cancels the request, and starts a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a new AJAX request every time a key is pressed is not the way to display a dynamic list of data.

#### Alternate approach 1

When the page is loaded, find a sane and reasonably quick way to load all the contacts that could possibly be relevant to the page. Filter the list as the user types without any AJAX after the initial content was loaded.

#### Alternate approach 2

Limit the amount of times your AJAX call is executed - something like a setTimeout to check if the input text has changed every 250 milliseconds or so. This may perform poorly depending on how quickly your server can respond to the AJAX request, and the response time is not ever guaranteed to be within the 250 millisecond threshold, so I would not use this approach.